# Using Basemap in python to plot country freqency

Tags: list, python-2.7, matplotlib-basemap

I'm doing visualization project, where I'm using the imdb API to illuminate some different aspects.
I would like to show on a basemap where most of the movies have been made. 
I have already created a list of the most popular countries,and would now like to add it to my basemap so the often a country has been used the more red it gets. (Using a barometer - from light yellow to dark red).

My question is, how do I implement my list in the basemap?
My list is as follows:

```
[304, 60, 18, 0, 3, 8, 6, 14, 14, 2, 6, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 0, 2, 13, 3, 3, 5, 0, 2, 1, 1, 12]
```

For now we have created a standard basemap with the code:

**Update:**

Well, so far I managed creating a colorbar which i also need. But i still do not know how to color countries and use my list with feqrency countries.

For example, 304 stands for USA :)

**Code:**

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

m = Basemap(projection='mill',llcrnrlat=-90,urcrnrlat=90,\
        llcrnrlon=-160,urcrnrlon=160,resolution='c')

m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries(color='black')
m.drawmapboundary()

#Colorbar

# The number of divisions of the cmap we have
k = 400

A = np.random.random((10,10))*k
c = cmap_discretize('autumn', 3)

# First show without

plt.imshow(A,interpolation='nearest',cmap=c)
plt.colorbar()



plt.title('Imdb Top250 feq countries')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use colormap for that. While making a plot use `cmap` parameter and select an appropriate colormap. You can see examples here - http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html

Comment: Could you maybe tell what i should look for? it's the first time i ever using basemap for a project. I really don't know what to do at this point.

Right now i looked as some parameter for drawcoastlines, where i can make the lake turned blue. Hmm

Comment: see this playlist - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wAwQ-noyB98&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfpEcGUM6ogsbrlWtqpS5-1

Comment: Well now i know how to make dots, but can't seem to find out how to give each countries a color based on freqency..